How can I solve this problem? error flutter --disable-analytics
i can't add any package in my terminal
I always get this answer:

Got dependencies!
Dependencies are affected by security advisories:
  [^0]: https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9324-jv53-9cc8
  [^1]: https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-jwpw-q68h-r678
111 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
The Flutter CLI developer tool uses Google Analytics to report usage and diagnostic
data along with package dependencies, and crash reporting to send basic crash
reports. This data is used to help improve the Dart platform, Flutter framework,
and related tools.

Telemetry is not sent on the very first run. To disable reporting of telemetry,
run this terminal command:

    flutter --disable-analytics

If you opt out of telemetry, an opt-out event will be sent, and then no further
information will be sent. This data is collected in accordance with the Google
Privacy Policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy).

Please note that analytics reporting was already disabled, and will continue to be disabled.



Did you try run this command in terminal: flutter --disable-analytics ?

Please include the specific command you are running, the package you are trying to add and the output of flutter doctor.  The information given is not sufficient to answer the question.

As per the advisory you have to upgrade packages that they mentioned to latest ones and its recommanded.
change dio to latest version or version > 5.0.0
Once you upgrade this package to this version you will not get longer this issue.
